# How to make a div into a translatable circle? 3D

Tags: html, css, 3d

I am trying to make a menu like in the picture. But I couldn't adjust the perspective. Can you please help? I'm going to rotate it up and down with a javascript event, but I can't turn it into a 3D cylinder.

```css
.righ-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0;
}

.footer-menu {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.righ-menu {
    float: right;
    width: 100%%;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    font-size: 70px;
    padding-right: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   line-height: 170px;
   scroll-behavior:unset;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transform: rotateY(.4deg); transform-origin: -100% 0; 
  transform: skewY(-1.5deg); 
  transform-origin: 300%; 
}

.righ-menu div {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;   
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotateX(348.75deg) rotateY(-2deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateZ(300px);
    perspective-origin: 75% 80%;
    background-position-x : -184px; 
    
}
```

```html
<div class="righ-menu">
            <div class="director" style="--i:1;">
                <a href="#" class="underline">Lorem Ipsum 1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="director" style="--i:2;">
                <a href="#" class="underline">Lorem Ipsum 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="director" style="--i:3;">
                <a href="#" class="underline">Lorem Ipsum 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="director" style="--i:4;">
                <a href="#" class="underline">Lorem Ipsum 4</a>
            </div>
            <div class="director" style="--i:5;">
                <a href="#" class="underline">Lorem Ipsum 5</a>
            </div>
            <div class="director" style="--i:6;">
                <a href="#" class="underline">Lorem Ipsum 6</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you very much to everyone who helped.

Comment: have you tried using `translate3d()`?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQyOL1u10EI&t=421s&ab_channel=OnlineTutorials Thank you very much for your help. This video solved my problem.